# Proof of $ \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n F_i = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n E_i $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove the following relations: For any sequence of events $E_1,E_2,\dots$, define a new sequence $F_1,F_2,\dots,$ of disjoint events (that is, events such that $F_i\cap F_j=\emptyset$ whenever $i\neq j$) such that for all $n\geq 1$,
$$ \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n F_i = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n E_i $$

Proof: Define $F_i=E_i \backslash \left(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j \right)$ for all $i$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x\in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n F_i 
& \iff x\in F_i  \text{ for all } i=1,\dots,n \\
& \iff x\in E_i \backslash \left(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j \right) \text{ for all } i=1,\dots,n \\
& \iff x\in E_i 
\text{ and } x\not\in \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j \text{ for all } i=1,\dots,n \\
& \iff x\in E_i 
\text{ and } x\not\in E_j \text{ for all } i=1,\dots,n \text{ and } j=1,\dots, i-1\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Note that last statement implies disjointness. So an element of $E_1$ only appears in $E_1$ .

Can I just state that the last statement is $ \iff x\in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n E_i$? Or do I have to mention something more?

Comment: Hi! Why is this in `statistics`? Are the $E_i$ events?

Comment: The reasoning is false from the beginning. In fact $x\in \cup F_i \Leftrightarrow x\in F_i$ for some $i \in \{1\cdots n\}$ (not all $i$)

Comment: The reasoning is false from the beginning. In fact x∈∪Fi⇔x∈Fi for exactly one i∈{1⋯n}.  The $F_i$ are defined to be disjoint.

Comment: @Gribouillis You are right! So aside from that is everything else correct so far?

Comment: @BrianTung What tags to do think this question should have

Comment: I would suggest `elementary set theory` myself. But you should edit the tags and enter some terms into the search bar to see what pops up. Read the descriptions carefully to pick the best one; some sound like they would fit, but upon closer examination, they have a different scope, etc.

Comment: As for your question, the reasoning that you should be formalizing is as follows: Think of the $E_i$ as lists of things, where some lists may overlap. Then $F_1$ is $E_1$; $F_2$ is whatever is in $E_2$ that is "new"—i.e., not in $E_1$; $F_3$ is whatever is in $E_3$ that is not in $E_1$ or $E_2$; and so on. Now, is it possible that there is an element in one of the $E_i$ that *never* shows up in one of the $F_i$? How about *vice versa*?

Comment: Hint: Don't be too greedy. Prove that $x\in\cup F_i \Rightarrow x\in\cup E_i$. Then prove the converse implication. Don't try to prove $\Longleftrightarrow$ directly.

Comment: @Gribouillis Won't by construction $F_i\subset E_i$ so the $\rightarrow$ is basically given?

Comment: @BrianTung I tried to tag you in the last comment. But I can only tag 1 person at a time. So here is me tagging you :)

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Indeed, $(\forall i, F_i \subset E_i) \Rightarrow (\cup_i F_i \subset \cup_i E_i)$.

Comment: @Gribouillis How should I do the other direction $\cup E_i \subset \cup F_i$? I know $x\in \cup E_i \Rightarrow x\in E_i$ for some $i$. But from there, i don't know

Comment: @UsernameUnknown If it belongs to some $E_i$, do you think it necessary belongs to the same $F_i$? What happens if it does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_1,E_2,\dots$ be a sequence of events. Now define a new sequence of events $F_1, F_2,\dots$ of disjoint events in the following manner:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
F_1 & = E_1 \\
F_2 & = E_2 - E_1 = E_2 \backslash E_1 \\
F_3 & = E_3 - E_1 - E_2 = E_3 \backslash (E_1 \cup E_2) \\
\vdots \\
F_i & = E_i \left\backslash \left(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j \right)\right. \text{ for all } i
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
By construction of $F_i$,
$$ \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n F_i \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n E_i $$
What is left to show is the other direction.

Let $x\in\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n E_i \iff x\in E_j$ for some $j$. By the well ordering principle of the natural numbers, we can say that there exists $i_0$ such that $x\in E_{i_0}$ and $x\not\in E_k$ for $k<i_0$. Hence $x\in F_{i_0}$ and thus $x\in\bigcup_{i=0}^n F_j$.

Comment: Just because $x \in E_i$ does not mean that $x \in \bigcup_{i=0}^{n} F_i$. The union of the $F_i$ sets misses the elements that the $E_i$ sets share with one another.

Answer (score 0):

$\space\space\space$ As has been mentioned in the comments, this proof doesn't really work. We do have a relation between the sets $F_i$ and $E_i$ but it is not what you have stated. Using your definition of $F_i$, we have;

$$x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} F_i \iff x\in F_i \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\cdots ,n\} $$

$$\iff x\in E_i \setminus \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}E_j\right) \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\cdots ,n\}$$

$$\iff x\in E_i \space \land \space x\ \not\in \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}E_j \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\cdots ,n\}$$

$$\iff x\in E_i \space \land \space x\ \not\in E_j \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\cdots ,n\} \text { and for all } j \in {\{1,\cdots ,i-1\}} $$

So, every $x$ in some $F_i$ does, indeed, appear in only one $E_i$. However, not every $x$ in some $E_i$ is covered by the $F_i$ sets. Namely, the union of the $F_i$ sets is missing, precisely, the intersection of the $E_i$ sets. So the actual relation between the union of the $F_i$ sets and the $E_i$ sets would be;

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}F_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}E_i \setminus \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}E_i \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the given definition of $F_i = F_i=E_i \backslash\left(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j \right)$ we get :-
$$x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} F_i \iff x\in F_i \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\cdots ,n\}$$
$$\iff x\in E_i \setminus \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}E_j\right) \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\cdots ,n\}$$
$$\iff x\in E_i \space \land \space x\ \not\in \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}E_j \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\cdots ,n\}$$
Now this as mentioned implies disjointness. Also $F_i\subseteq E_i$ for $i \in\{1,\cdots ,n\}$ and also $F_i\not\in \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}E_j$
Now let $$y \in E_i \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\cdots ,n\}$$
$$\iff y\in E_i \setminus \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}E_j\right) \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\cdots ,n\} \hspace 1cm \text{ [This is as all }E_i\text{ are disjoint] }$$
$$\iff y\in F_i \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$$
Thus $E_i\subseteq F_i$ for $i \in\{1,\cdots ,n\}$
Thus it follows that $E_i = F_i$
So we conclude:-
$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n F_i = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n E_i$$